# Sailsjs : check user

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, sails.js

i'm trying to check if user already exite before register but not work for me
when i test in postman it's still created user  any idea ?

```
  create: function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'Password doesn\'t match, What a shame!'});
    }
    User.find(req.body).exec(function(err,users){

          if (err) {
            return res.negotiate(err);
        }
        if (users.length) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.json('User already exists!');
        } 

    }else{
        User.create(req.body).exec(function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json(err.status, {err: err});
          }
          // If user created successfuly we return user and token as response
          if (user) {
            // NOTE: payload is { id: user.id}
            res.json(200, {user: user, token: jwToken.issue({id: user.id})});
          }
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: `User.find()` takes a [Waterline criteria](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md), not just an object.

Comment: @Claies i'm try `User.find({email:params.email})` but not works

Comment: why did you change from `req.body` to `params`?  your create function doesn't even have a `params` property.

Comment: @Claies i'm hava already all params `var params=req.params.all();`

Comment: There is a handy method in sails that finds or creates :)
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create

Answer (score 0):

try  edit your code in this lines

```
User.find(req.body).exec(function(err,users){});
```

to :-

```
   User.findOne({email:params.email}).exec(function(err,user){
    if(user){
    /**
    *user exists !
    */
    }else{
    /**
    *create new user 
    */
    }
```

}

> because you use find with criteria which isn't exist so it's returns
>   null and create new user in every time

Comment: not work for me when i try to create new email it's display error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have users with unique username and/or email you can use `unique` type in model's [attribute definition](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes) like this:

```
attributes: {
  username: {
    type: 'string',
    unique: true
  }
}
```

Then your controller method would look like this:

```
create: function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'Password doesn\'t match, What a shame!'});
    }
    User.create(req.body, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.negotiate(err); // validation error will be automatically passed there
      }
      res.json(200, {user: user, token: jwToken.issue({id: user.id})});
    });
});
```